# Automated deployment of smart contract

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-deployment, truffle-migration

Is it possible to **automate the deployment of smart contract using git**??
As we know it impossible to update existing contract but we can manage the update of contract by using entry level contract, but this whole process is manual, I want to automate the deployment ie. as soon as any thing is updated in contract on git it should be updated on blockchain.

Comment: You can deploy the contract using Web3JS and with that, you can automate the deployment of the contract as well.

Comment: But this can be expensive it want any change in git repo to be deployed in the blockchain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Github offers [webhooks](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/) so that you can 'do things' when certain events occur.

Both Geth and Parity implement the [JSON RPC API](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC) so in principle you can interface with the Ethereum blockchain from any programming language.

The API method you want is `eth_sendRawTransaction`. You can build a transaction signature and submit it to the chain.

[web3.js](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/) removes a lot of the complexities (if working with JS).

PHP [JsonRPC](https://github.com/fguillot/JsonRPC) makes the communication aspect of things easy if working with PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this using a git post-commit (or post-receive) hook and truffle migrate.

https://git-scm.com/book/gr/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks
http://truffle.readthedocs.io/en/beta/getting_started/migrations/

Comment: thanks for your answer, it would be better if you redact a complete answer instead posting the links